# 'textContains' after edge traversal returns different result

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I found out some unexpected result from my gremlin queries like below.
The 'textContains' looks like search different index term when it is used after some edge related queries.
I know that the textContains after edge queries can't use mixed index but I expect that returns same result.

Environment:

- Janusgraph 0.3.1
- gremlinpython 3.4.3

Test:

(textContains with 'CULTURE_PERSON' returns doc)

- gremlin> g.V().has("DOC_ID", "doc_person_8428").has("DOC_CATEGORY", **textContains("CULTURE_PERSON")**).valueMap("DOC_ID", "DOC_TITLE", "DOC_CATEGORY")
- ==>[DOC_TITLE:[James Lee],DOC_ID:[doc_person_8428],DOC_CATEGORY:[**CULTURE_PERSON**,THING,ENTERTAINER,ACTOR,PERSON]]

(textContains with 'CULTURE' doesn't return doc)

- gremlin> g.V().has("DOC_ID", "doc_person_8428").has("DOC_CATEGORY", **textContains("CULTURE")**).valueMap("DOC_ID", "DOC_TITLE", "DOC_CATEGORY")
- ==>NONE

**(Expected Result)**

- gremlin> g.V().has("DOC_ID", "doc_film_349274").outE("FILM-MAIN_ACTOR").otherV().has("DOC_ID", "doc_person_8428").has("DOC_CATEGORY", **textContains("CULTURE")**).valueMap("DOC_ID", "DOC_TITLE", "DOC_CATEGORY")
- ==>NONE

**(Actual Result)**

- gremlin> g.V().has("DOC_ID", "doc_film_349274").outE("FILM-MAIN_ACTOR").otherV().has("DOC_ID", "doc_person_8428").has("DOC_CATEGORY", **textContains("CULTURE")**).valueMap("DOC_ID", "DOC_TITLE", "DOC_CATEGORY")
- ==>[DOC_TITLE:[James Lee],DOC_ID:[doc_person_8428],DOC_CATEGORY:[**CULTURE_PERSON**,THING,ENTERTAINER,ACTOR,PERSON]]